# Laravel 5.8 on validation error return to specific view with all input -> old not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

> TLDR;
>
> **(In Laravel 5.8) Upon validation error, how can I return to a specific view with all input and the errors?**

I'm creating a multistep form in which I need to validate the input on each step. Therefore, I have created the first page as a create and then the subsequent pages to update.

On the second page, when the validator fails, I am returning the specific view as I want it to go to this partial and not the beginning of the form. I am also returning the errors and the input on fail.

Controller:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return view('partials.question_02_' . $type)
        ->with('type', $type)
        ->with('id', $id)
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput($request->all());
}
```

Here is my validation logic:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email'               => 'required',
    'first_name'          => 'required',
    'last_name'           => 'required',
    'phone'               => 'required',
]);
```

With this, I am able to go back to the specific view and with the validation errors. However, I am not able to receive the old input.

The following in Blade will show that there is an erro (the *error* class appears), however, it will not show the old input.

```
<input class="@if ($errors->has('first_name')) error @endif" 
type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}">
```

<sup>*note, I only put it on two lines for legibility here</sup>

What is weird is that if I die and dump the request, I can see all of the input:

```
dd($request->all());
```

However, if I try to get it from the session, I don't see any of the input:

```
@if($errors)
    {{var_dump(Session::all())}}
@endif
```

**Any idea why {{ old('first_name') }} isn't working in this case?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your validation logic?

Comment: Also you don't need to pass any parameters to `->withInput();`

Comment: @AdityaThakur, I have added the validation logic. What do you think?

Comment: @AdityaThakur, when I added ->withInput(); without the parameters, it failed, giving me an Undefined offset: 0 error

Comment: instead of return view(), you need return redirect(); return view will load up a fresh page.

Comment: @AdityaThakur, I have tried return redirect()->back() and return back(). Unfortunately, both of these return me to step 1 instead of step 2, which I am on. I have also tried return->redirect()->view(), but that threw an error (Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::view does not exist.)

Comment: your second page is generated using a route?

Comment: I was generating it with the following code after I submitted the form: 

return view('partials.question_02_' . $leads->type). However, I am now trying to see if I redirect to this page instead of returning it will work. Maybe this will keep it at the second step on redirect->back()

Comment: you can redirect to the controller method which is generating your second page `return redirect()->action('LoginController@secondPage');`

Comment: Excellent! It worked! I had to add a few parameters to the "action" tag, but it worked! :) :) Thanks so much @AdityaThakur ! If you'd like, you can respond and I will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're Returning a view `return view()` instead you need to return redirect `return redirect()`as a return view will generate a fresh page and old() will not work.

So instead of

```
return view('partials.question_02_' . $type)
```

Use

```
return redirect()
```

&in your case

```
redirect()->action('LoginController@secondPage'); //you controller and method handling your second page
```